# When to use a SortedMap interface?

Tags: java, interfaces, type-theory

The rule in programming is to use the most general interface possible. But the difference between `Map` and `SortedMap` is more subtle.

- They compile to the same bytecode [I think]
- No additional safety is provided since the compiler can't tell any of the differences between the two
- SortedMap does offer an extra non-compiler-checked post condition, namely that the iterator is sorted

I would prefer code to write

```
SortedMap<K, V> m = new TreeMap<>();
```

if the sorted-ness is used. But I'm not sure if this rule only makes sense when there's compiler checks.

I'm hoping for a somewhat rigorous (e.g. type-theoretical) answer, but since this pertains to a real code review I'm doing right now, how this applies in practice is definitely important. I've yet to find an effective example of why one matters, besides a readability bump that circularly depends on programmers following this theory.

Comment: *The rule in programming is to use the most general interface possible* -- [citation-needed]

Comment: `Map` and `SortedMap` are interfaces. They do not really "do" anything other than specify what actions you can take through a reference of type (that interface). Specifically, an interface cannot impose restrictions on the implementations of that interface. For all `SortedMap` knows, its implementations may or may not actually be sorted.

Comment: @Snowman that's called a buggy implementation and you shouldn't use them. But part of the weird thing here is it's just out of Java's reach of compile-time safety.

Comment: @djechlin right, there is a difference between an interface's _explicit_ interface (you must implement this method with this signature, or be abstract) and its _implicit_ interface (this method _should_ behave a certain way). For example, it is implicit in the language that a "get" method should not mutate state but the compile is incapable of enforcing that. C++ allows the `const` keyword for methods which does (mostly) enforce that when used consistently, but Java has nothing but hopes and dreams.

Comment: You're expecting *way* too much from the type system. No matter how much you want to believe that types rigourously define behavior, it comes down to implementation by an ordinary human. In the case of Java interfaces, there's no pretense; the interface describes a contract, with luck that contract doesn't have too many corner cases, hopefully the people who implement classes based on that interface  follow the contract without bugs, and the consumers of that interface use it in its intended manner.

Comment: It's not at all weird that some property of some type is not statically verifiable automagically. That's pretty much the general case. There's no guarantee that any of the methods you call actually terminates, for example.

Comment: @Doval I still don't feel that's relevant. The type system only can't protect against this because at some point a programmer has to write a valid object and it would only be possible to validate this by using an abstract class which checks instead of an interface. That would be the strictest thing to do, it's just not worth the tradeoff. But just because the type system can't do it doesn't mean you should jump for joy that you can now write bad code. The question is: is this bad code? and saying the type system doesn't answer it, IMO even though it "wants" to, doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't know about Java, but using the Most General Type is standard practice in functional programming / typed lambda calculus / generic programming. In general, it makes sense even for Java: you should use the constraints you need, and only those you need. There is good reason for this: the fewer assumptions you make about a type, the fewer mistakes you can commit.

Comment: @djechlin It's not clear to me what you're asking. Your question title and the question body are at odds with each other. If you just want to know when to use a `SortedMap`, the answer is obvious: when you need the map to be sorted. But you seem dissatisfied with that, and reading between the lines it seems you're asking if there's value in relying on interfaces that have specifications that can't be statically enforced, even though any non-trivial program implicitly relies on dozens of such interfaces. It would be nice if you edited the question to really reflect what you want to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use it when you want to guarantee that you are getting sorted data in a parameter, or when you want to assure the consumer of your method that you are *providing* sorted data.

#### Parameters

If you need your data to be sorted, ask for it to be sorted by asking for the interface that matches what you need. It is likely less expensive for the method sending you the data to give it to you sorted (they get it from a database and can trivially order it, but instead tossed it in a `HashMap` because thats what everyone uses) than it is for you to take the `Map` and then add it to a `SortedMap`.

If you need it to be sorted, ask for it to be sorted.

#### Return values

This one is a bit more controversial... there are differing schools of thought here.

If you are *producing* sorted data by the nature of your method and don't have a reason *not* to, return back the interface that lets the consumers of your data work with it in the most ways *without* giving them a concrete implementation (that locks you down).

That 'that locks you down' is part of the controversial bit.  Some people will argue that you should return the least constraining (most general) interface when possible (`Map` rather than `SortedMap` and `Collection` rather than `Set` or `List`).

I'd go with return the most *useful* thing for the consumers.

I will put the caveat here that if this is something that will *always* be sorted, its one thing... if someone might want to subclass it later and not have it be sorted... thats another story.  So you need to consider this as part of [designing for extension](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html#DesignForExtension).  If it isn't going to be extended *ever* you get one answer from this deliberation... if it may be extended, there's another possible answer.

***why is this bit above a mess and people say things about it in code review?***

Well, [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) points out that this would make it harder to subclass later.  Method parameters cannot be strengthened by a subtype and return values cannot be relaxed.

By returning a `SortedMap` one cannot make a later subclass of the class return a weaker type.  Furthermore, if you decide to return a weaker type later for some reason it makes it a major refactoring (changing all of the SortedMaps out there to Maps and possibly changing the calls that make use of that interface into code that has to deal with the weaker type).

#### Your internals

It really doesn't matter what you are doing inside your own code.  Use a sorted map whenever you've got sorted data and want it in a sorted order. Especially if you are doing `put` calls on it at various times and want it to remain in sorted order.

Now, you might be tempted to use a `LinkedHashMap` instead if you get all the sorted data in one go, insert it in sorted order, and then only do `remove` calls against it if you do any modifications.  It's not wrong, and it has some advantages (O(1) lookups rather than O(log n) lookups).  But, its rather inflexible only providing the `get` and `put` and none of the other fun method calls that `SortedMap` can give you.

#### Btw, NavigableMap

Actually, `SortedMap` doesn't give you that much more over `Map`.  But there is something else...

`SortedMap` has been replaced by `NavigableMap` since Java 1.6 (the two standard classes that implement `SortedMap` also implement `NavigableMap`).  [NavigableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) has all sorts of fun method calls that are often quite useful.

Comment: It's an internal case which is why it's so hard to point to a practical matter. I forgot what LSP is called so that's really helpful.

Comment: @djechlin Internal development poses its own challenges with the messy refactoring if you need to relax the return type rather than just releasing a 2.0 version that has a breaking API change (thats 'easy' to do). So, thats the practical reason *not* to, but on the other hand if you need it, or want to be reminded of its functionality as a sorted (or navigable) structure, its useful to return back that so you get the '`foo.` control-space, ohh `ceilingEntry` thats would be useful here rather than coding it myself...'

Comment: Oh, I mean it's a private member variable. It's hard to come up with a plausible thought experiment where it matters, especially given unit test coverage on the sortedness.

Comment: @djechlin ahh, so even *more* internal then.  Well, use the method that makes it the most useful (NavigableMap) if it is to be sorted at all. The only thing inspections that fuss about the types of private fields are ones that point out you are using the concrete type when an interface exists.

Comment: Re: Return values, the most flexible approach is to let the caller provide the collection for you to fill. Any choice you make will be wrong for someone, and subclassing should generally be avoided. It's also a lot easier on the caller to pass you an empty collection than to subclass your class just to change the collection you decided to instantiate.

Comment: @Doval but, if they pass you an instance of a TreeMap and you change your code so that the objects you are putting in there don't have a natural sort order things break in ugly ways at runtime. It is difficult to specify "give me an instance of a Map, but not a Sorted Map."

Comment: @MichaelT I don't see the difficulty; if the caller doesn't read the documentation, he deserves whatever happens next. He's already read at least some of it if he knows the collection will be mutated. Note that nothing stops the caller from giving the `TreeMap` a `Comparator`. Even if the object were `Comparable`, the caller may want a different ordering from the "natural" one. And if he really needs things to be ordered, then he's probably aware of whether the objects have a default ordering or not.

Comment: @Doval that implies that the caller has control of the type being populated in the Map or is otherwise tightly related to it. If that is not the case, then it is possible for the caller to specify a structure that works today that doesn't work (and discovered at runtime) tomorrow. The advantage that the weakening of the return type has over this is that when the change is made it is a compile time issue which is easier to detect and solve.

Comment: @MichaelT Not really. I can write a comparator for `String`s without controlling the `String` class. That's robust as long as I only rely on publicly documented features. If you insist that the class being added to the collection can break its contracts, there's no retort I can give you, but this conversation is also pointless; it makes no sense to argue over the most future-proof way to return a collection when you've already established you're not future-proofed against a different class.

Answer (score -1):

While it is true that in programming it is a good idea to always

> *"use the most general interface possible"*

it is **even more** true that

> *"everything should be as simple as possible **--but not simpler**"*.

So, if your code only needs to work with a `Map`, then your code should be given a `Map` and nothing more specific than that.  This way, your code will work when either a `Map` or a `SortedMap` is passed to it, and the code which uses your code will be able to pass it whichever best suits its own needs.

***However***, if your code needs to work with a `SortedMap`, then you cannot somehow work around that and continue using a `Map` under the false pretense of keeping things simple; your code will, of course, need to be given a `SortedMap`. This will happen if your code needs to make use of any methods which are specific to `SortedMap` (do not exist in `Map`) i.e. `comparator()`, `subMap()`, `headMap()`, `tailMap()`, `firstKey()`, and `lastKey()`.

The above was fairly self-explanatory, so I suspect that the reason why you are asking the question is because you have misunderstood what `SortedMap` is.  So, here are a few notes about your question:

> They compile to the same bytecode [I think]

`SortedMap` is an interface without any `default` methods, it does not really compile into bytecode.  The `.class` file of that interface contains nothing but function declarations.  Now, some of the methods declared by `SortedMap` are also declared by `Map`, and the reason why these declarations were duplicated in `SortedMap` was probably to add new documentation to them, but many methods of `SortedMap` do not exist in `Map`.

(Useful reading: [What is the difference between declaration and definition in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11715485/773113))

> No additional safety is provided since the compiler can't tell any of the differences 
>   between the two

Huh?  This does not make any sense.  I am not sure what you are thinking, but whatever it is, it is probably wrong.

> SortedMap does offer an extra non-compiler-checked post condition, namely that the iterator is sorted

`SortedMap` begins with a doc comment which is about 4 kilobytes long, explaining what it is and how it differs from `Map`.  I am not sure it is a good idea to summarize this as "does offer an extra non-compiler-checked post condition".  Perhaps you should read the documentation.

Comment: Your first example is a case of "Use the most general type/interface possible": `Map` is more general than `SortedMap`; hence, if you just need a `Map`, use a `Map`. No need to invoke the second principle about simplicity :)

Comment: @AndresF. the principle about simplicity needs to be invoked to show that if you ***need*** a `SortedMap`, then ***you have to*** use a `SortedMap`, there is no way around it. It is the ***"--but not simpler"*** clause that matters.  I will amend the answer to emphasize that.